# How do I combine these two python scripts?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gps

Currently having problems combining two of my codes into one. **Code 1** prints out GPS data continuously, but once I add **Code 2** it only prints out once. I suspect the while-loop might be the problem but I don't know for sure.

Any help would be appreciated :)

**Combined code:**

```
import os
import sys
import time
import serial
import datetime
from gps import *

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)

moment = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M",time.localtime())

try:
    gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
except:
    print('ERROR: Cannot set time')
    sys.exit()


while True:
    gpsd.next()
    if gpsd.utc != None and gpsd.utc != '':
        gpsutc = gpsd.utc[0:4] + gpsd.utc[5:7] + gpsd.utc[8:10] + ' ' + gpsd.utc[11:19]
        os.system('sudo date -u --set="%s"' % gpsutc)
        sys.exit()
    
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        x = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
        file = open('GPS ' + moment + '.txt', "a")
        file.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3] + "  ")
        file.write(str(x))
        file.close()
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S.%f  ")[:-3])
        print(x)
```

**Code 1 (collects GPS data and stores to text files):**

```
import time
import serial
import datetime

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
    timeout = 1
)

moment = time.strftime(%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", time.localtime())
                       
while True:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        x = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
        file = open('GPS ' + moment + '.txt', "a")
        file.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S.%f)[:-3] + "  ")
        file.write(str(x))
        file.close()
```

**Code 2 (Sets Raspberry Pi time to equal GPS time):**

```
import os
import sys
import time
from gps import *

try:
    gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
except:
    print('ERROR: Cannot set time')
    sys.exit()
    
while True:
    gpsd.next()
    if gpsd.utc != None and gpsd.utc != '':
        gpsutc = gpsd.utc[0:4] + gpsd.utc[5:7] + gpsd.utc[8:10] + ' ' + gpsd.utc[11:19]
        os.system('sudo date -u --set="%s"' % gpsutc)
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do overall, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't own GPS hardware, so i cannot verify, but the second sys.exit() in the combined code stings my eye:
I assume the corresponding sys.exit() in code 2 just ends the script once the time could be read successfully - which makes sense.
But in the combined script, it will still end the whole script.

My first idea was to remove it, but then you will re-set the system time quite often which might cause further issues; maybe it is better keep two loops in the combined script, just replacing that one sys.exit() by break. Something like:

```py
import os
import sys
import time
import serial
import datetime
from gps import *

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)

moment = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M",time.localtime())

try:
    gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
except:
    print('ERROR: Cannot set time')
    sys.exit()

while True:
    gpsd.next()
    if gpsd.utc != None and gpsd.utc != '':
        gpsutc = gpsd.utc[0:4] + gpsd.utc[5:7] + gpsd.utc[8:10] + ' ' + gpsd.utc[11:19]
        os.system('sudo date -u --set="%s"' % gpsutc)
        break

while True:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        x = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
        file = open('GPS ' + moment + '.txt', "a")
        file.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3] + "  ")
        file.write(str(x))
        file.close()
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S.%f  ")[:-3])
        print(x)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).